# What does it mean for two graphs to be consistent

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to understand what does it really means for two graphs to be consistent in the context of bidirectional transformation ? Can you provide me with a good example? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I do not think this is a standard term, if you do not offer more context then this question may be impossible to answer.

Comment: I have updated the question.